# net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException: Tried to access ended session SessionId(toLong=8223329095323268472) with empty buffer

Tags: corda

i*m using Corda 4.0 RC1 and have a clone of the cash-issuer repository; there i have a Corda-ResponderFlow which should do a business test; currently it throws an exception; the flow is programmed in this way

```
class ReceiveBankAccount(val otherSession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        logger.info("Starting ReceiveBankAccount flow...")

        val signedTransactionFlow = object : SignTransactionFlow(otherSession) {
            @Suspendable
            override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) = requireThat {
                val bankAccountState = stx.tx.outputsOfType<BankAccountState>().single()
                val result = getBankAccountStateByAccountNumber(bankAccountState.accountNumber, serviceHub)
                if (result != null) {
                    val linearId = result.state.data.linearId
                    throw IllegalArgumentException("Bank account $bankAccountState already exists with linearId ($linearId).")
                }
            }
        }

        subFlow(signedTransactionFlow)

        if (!serviceHub.myInfo.isLegalIdentity(otherSession.counterparty)) {
            subFlow(ReceiveFinalityFlow(otherSession))
        }
    }
}
```

after the execution of the parent corda-flow `AddBankAccount` i get the following error `net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException: Tried to access ended session SessionId(toLong=8223329095323268472) with empty buffer`
what do i wrong? can anybody help me?

my stack trace is

```
net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException: Tried to access ended session SessionId(toLong=8017581909056924623) with empty buffer
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.processEventsUntilFlowIsResumed(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:161) ~[corda-node-4.0-RC01.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.suspend(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:407) ~[corda-node-4.0-RC01.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowSessionImpl.receive(FlowSessionImpl.kt:67) ~[corda-node-4.0-RC01.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowSessionImpl.receive(FlowSessionImpl.kt:71) ~[corda-node-4.0-RC01.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.SignTransactionFlow.call(CollectSignaturesFlow.kt:294) ~[corda-core-4.0-RC01.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.SignTransactionFlow.call(CollectSignaturesFlow.kt:198) ~[corda-core-4.0-RC01.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.subFlow(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:290) ~[corda-node-4.0-RC01.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:311) ~[corda-core-4.0-RC01.jar:?]
    at com.r3.corda.finance.cash.issuer.service.flows.ReceiveBankAccount.call(ReceiveBankAccount.kt:31) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.r3.corda.finance.cash.issuer.service.flows.ReceiveBankAccount.call(ReceiveBankAccount.kt:12) ~[classes/:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:228) ~[corda-node-4.0-RC01.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:45) ~[corda-node-4.0-RC01.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:63) ~[corda-node-4.0-RC01.jar:?]
```

```
 @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        logger.info("Starting AddBankAccount flow...")
        val accountNumber = bankAccount.accountNumber

        logger.info("Checking for existence of state for $bankAccount.")
        val result = getBankAccountStateByAccountNumber(accountNumber, serviceHub)

        if (result != null) {
            val linearId = result.state.data.linearId
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Bank account $accountNumber already exists with linearId ($linearId).")
        }

        logger.info("No state for $bankAccount. Adding it.")
        progressTracker.currentStep = TX_BUILDING
        val bankAccountState = bankAccount.toState(ourIdentity, verifier)
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities.first()
        val verifierSsession = initiateFlow(bankAccountState.verifier)

        // The node running this flow is always the only signer.
        val command = Command(BankAccountContract.Add(), listOf(ourIdentity.owningKey))
        val outputStateAndContract = StateAndContract(bankAccountState, BankAccountContract.CONTRACT_ID)
        val unsignedTransaction = TransactionBuilder(notary = notary).withItems(command, outputStateAndContract)

        progressTracker.currentStep = TX_SIGNING
        val partiallySignedTransaction = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(unsignedTransaction)

        progressTracker.currentStep = TX_VERIFICATION
        partiallySignedTransaction.verify(serviceHub)

        progressTracker.currentStep = SIGS_GATHERING
        val sessionsForFinality = if (serviceHub.myInfo.isLegalIdentity(bankAccountState.verifier)) emptyList() else listOf(verifierSsession)
        val fullySignedTx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partiallySignedTransaction, sessionsForFinality, SIGS_GATHERING.childProgressTracker()))

        progressTracker.currentStep = VERIFYING_SIGS
        fullySignedTx.verifyRequiredSignatures()

        progressTracker.currentStep = FINALISATION
        // Share the added bank account state with the verifier/issuer.
        return subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, sessionsForFinality, FINALISATION.childProgressTracker()))
    }
```

ERROR in InitiatorFlow:

```
flow start AddBankAccount bankAccount: { accountId: "12345", accountName: "Roger's Account", accountNumber: { sortCode: "442200" , accountNumber: "13371337", type: "uk" }, currency: "GBP" }, verifier: Issuer: exception: Collection contains no element matching the predicate.
Fri Jan 18 11:14:03 CET 2019>>> [ERROR] 11:14:03+0100 [pool-8-thread-2] command.CRaSHSession.execute - Error while evaluating request 'flow start AddBankAccount bankAccount: { accountId: "12345", accountName: "Roger's Account", accountNumber: { sortCode: "442200" , accountNumber: "13371337", type: "uk" }, currency: "GBP" }, verifier: Issuer' flow start AddBankAccount bankAccount: { accountId: "12345", accountName: "Roger's Account", accountNumber: { sortCode: "442200" , accountNumber: "13371337", type: "uk" }, currency: "GBP" }, verifier: Issuer: exception: Collection contains no element matching the predicate. [errorCode=hf0q78, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.0-RC01/hf0q78]
```

WARNs in InitiatorFlow:

```
[WARN] 11:14:07+0100 [rpc-client-observation-pool-1] internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.onRemoval - A hot observable returned from an RPC was never subscribed to. This wastes server-side resources because it was queueing observations for retrieval. It is being closed now, but please adjust your code to call .notUsed() on the observable to close it explicitly. (Java users: subscribe to it then unsubscribe). If you aren't sure where the leak is coming from, set -Dnet.corda.client.rpc.trackRpcCallSites=true on the JVM command line and you will get a stack trace with this warning.
[WARN] 11:14:07+0100 [rpc-client-observation-pool-1] internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.onRemoval - A hot observable returned from an RPC was never subscribed to. This wastes server-side resources because it was queueing observations for retrieval. It is being closed now, but please adjust your code to call .notUsed() on the observable to close it explicitly. (Java users: subscribe to it then unsubscribe). If you aren't sure where the leak is coming from, set -Dnet.corda.client.rpc.trackRpcCallSites=true on the JVM command line and you will get a stack trace with this warning.
[WARN] 11:14:07+0100 [rpc-client-observation-pool-1] internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.onRemoval - A hot observable returned from an RPC was never subscribed to. This wastes server-side resources because it was queueing observations for retrieval. It is being closed now, but please adjust your code to call .notUsed() on the observable to close it explicitly. (Java users: subscribe to it then unsubscribe). If you aren't sure where the leak is coming from, set -Dnet.corda.client.rpc.trackRpcCallSites=true on the JVM command line and you will get a stack trace with this warning.
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the full stacktrace, please? Also, what version of Corda are you using?

Comment: Hi Joel, i'm using Corda 4.0 RC 1; my stack trace is given above

Comment: the repository i'm using is taken from the cash-issuer done by Roger

Comment: Hmm - I can't see anything wrong. Can you post the other side of the flow (the part run by the initiator)?

Comment: it is the same flow as in the cash issuer repository: ```package com.r3.corda.finance.cash.issuer.common.flows.AddBankAccount```i have attached it above

Comment: Thanks. Can you check the logs of the initiating flow and see if there are any errors there too?

Comment: i have one ERROR and several WARNS (see above); i think i do something wrong with ```subFlow(signedTransactionFlow)``` if i do exactly not use this LOC there is no error; but surely also not my check ...

Answer (score 4):

You will have to add key of bankAccountState.verifier to command.

In your initiator flow change command from:

```
val command = Command(BankAccountContract.Add(), listOf(ourIdentity.owningKey))
```

to:

```
val command = Command(BankAccountContract.Add(), listOf(ourIdentity.owningKey,bankAccountState.verifier.owningKey))
```