# Corda How to Transact a Partially Signed transaction corda 4?

Tags: corda

I am trying to do the following scenario ,

There is a basic IOU transaction which is done from Party A to Party B in which Party A who is the initiator will only sign the transaction , Party B just accepts it(without signing) . To achieve the following I did the following things which worked fine in Corda 3 using the IOU flow of the corda samples project.

1. 1.In the transaction command , I just passed only the Initiator owning key instead of sending both the participants owning  keys
2. I removed the "All Signers" check from the contract
3. I removed the "Gather counter party signature" Step.

When I moved the same to corda 4 , I noticed the following

1. Since I am not setting the acceptors owning key as part of the
   txcommand , The transaction is saved in the initiator but not part
   of the acceptor because of session issue which I understood from the
   following.[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54235774/net-corda-core-flows-unexpectedflowendexception-tried-to-access-ended-session-s)
2. Looking at the reference I rectified it accordingly, now Corda is expecting the signing of the acceptor also which is against my use case, if I do not add , it is throwing the following error

   > 'net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction$SignaturesMissingException:Missing
   >   signatures on transaction '

Please let me know if any workaround is present on the same.

P.S : I am using the cordapp-example Java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was on the acceptor side , since I was using the SignTransactionFlow which expects the participants to all be signers. Once I commented the code and just ran the ReceiveFinalityFlow it worked fine. Reference : [SignTransactionFlow](https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.flows/-sign-transaction-flow/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the sample flow which achieves the same functionality**

```
  @InitiatingFlow
    @StartableByRPC
    class IssuerRegistration(
            val issuerData: IssuerData

    ) : BaseFlow<String>() {
        override val progressTracker = ProgressTracker()

        @Suspendable
        override fun call(): String {


// We retrieve the notary identity from the network map.
            val notary = firstNotary


// We create the transaction components.
            val meta_Info = Meta_Info("pdf", Utils.getCurrentDateTime(), Utils.getCurrentDateTime())
            val ids = Ids(issuerData.ids.dunsId)

//create list of all parties involved in this flow
            val partList = ArrayList<Party>()

            partList.add(ourIdentity)
            partList.add(createParty("partyb", serviceHub))



//random unique id of the state
            val userUniqueId = UUID.randomUUID()

//create output state actually this will
//save to related parties vault
            val outputState = IssuerState(userUniqueId.toString(),
                    issuerData.company_id,
                    issuerData.company_name,
                    issuerData.company_symbol,
                    ids,
                    meta_Info,
                    partList)


//registration command will be verified by issuercontract
            val command = Command(RegistrationCommand.IssuerRegistration(),
                    ourIdentity.owningKey)

// We create a transaction builder and add the components.
            val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary = notary)
                    .addOutputState(outputState, RegistrationContract.ID)
                    .addCommand(command)

// Verifying the transaction.
            txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)

// Signing the transaction. from sender side
            val signedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)

            val listOfSession = ArrayList<FlowSession>()
            //creating all other party session to get
            //signature from to validate the transaction

             val otherPartySession = initiateFlow(otherPartySession)
             listOfSession.add(otherPartySession)




//end the flow and write the transation data to related parties vault
            subFlow(FinalityFlow(signedTx, listOfSession))


            return userUniqueId.toString()
        }


    }

// Replace Responder's definition with:
    @InitiatedBy(Flows.IssuerRegistration::class)
    class IssueResponder(private val otherPartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
        @Suspendable
        override fun call() {
            subFlow(ReceiveFinalityFlow(otherPartySession))
        }
    }
```